# Doubts in networking and internet protocol

Tags: networking, routes, ip

I found hard to find the correct answer and explanation of following questions.

1.Can  packet source set the route of an outgoing packets?

2.The route is determined only by the routing tables in the routers on the way? true/false

In the explanation it is written that in usual routing algorithm employs an internet routing table on each machine that stores information about possible destination and how to reach them.Because both host and router determine the route so this statement is false.

But in my book i have not found that routing table is stored on the hosts too.

Please clear doubts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically [*] any IP node has control of exactly one hop of an outgoing packet route. In other words the IP node consults its routing table and decides whether to send it to some neighbor or the other. It has no further control on what that next node then decides to do with the packet.

Everybody needs a routing table. A simple host will have a few routes to decide to whom to send most if not all of its packets. A router will have many routes, being able to select many potential neighbors to continue handling the packet. But however way you put it, any one node has control exactly on the next node.

---

[*] Of course there is also source routing but we don't like to talk about it.

Comment: it means my own computer also has a routing table ? never heard about it and how it is managed? The thing that is causing problem to me suppose 802.11(wi-fi) we are connected to a particular router so we don't have choice for any other route??Please clear this doubt.

Comment: @SeemaYadav You do have a choice it's just that in 99.99% of the cases you just send the packet to the famous "default gateway". The routing table is managed with OS specific commands (for example `ip` on linux, `route` on most unices, `route` on Windows etc.)

Comment: And perhaps our computer build this table by consulting the routing table of the router/switch it is connected to or by some other management protocol??

Comment: @SeemaYadav Sorry, I meant DHCP and Neighbor Discovery.